# Sum by location- display Location as $0 when blank

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am summing amounts shipped by location.  There are 3 total locations.  Today I'm only getting results for one location as there are $0 for the other two.  I want to show those locations with $0.  The pic shows the location with shipments and I would like it to show the other two below it or on top with $0.
Included a snipped of the code

```
SELECT [Facility_Table].facility 'Facility', isnull(sum(exten),0) 'Shipped'
FROM dtorder
```

[image]

Here is some example DDL/DML

```
DECLARE @Locations TABLE (LocationID BIGINT IDENTITY, LocationName NVARCHAR(50))
DECLARE @Shipments TABLE (ShipmentID BIGINT IDENTITY, LocationID BIGINT, ShipmentAmount DECIMAL(10,4))

INSERT INTO @Locations (LocationName) VALUES
('Main Warehouse'),('New York Warehouse'),('Los Angeles Warehouse')

INSERT INTO @Shipments (LocationID, ShipmentAmount)
SELECT TOP 50 ROUND(((2 - 1) * Rnd1 + 1), 0), ROUND(((500 - 1) * Rnd1 + 1), 4)
  FROM (
        VALUES(
               RAND(CONVERT(VARBINARY,NEWID(),1)),
               RAND(CONVERT(VARBINARY,NEWID(),1))
              )
       ) a(Rnd1,Rnd2)
  CROSS APPLY sys.sysobjects
```

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` to your orders table, don't `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

As Larnu suggests, you will need to `LEFT OUTER JOIN` from your locations table to the shipments table. Using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` returns rows from the dataset even when there is no match to the joined table:

```
SELECT l.LocationName, SUM(COALESCE(s.ShipmentAmount,0)) AS TotalShipments
  FROM @Locations l
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @Shipments s
      ON l.LocationID = s.LocationID
 GROUP BY l.LocationName
```

| LocationName | TotalShipments |
| --- | --- |
| Los Angeles Warehouse | 0.0000 |
| Main Warehouse | 3392.0912 |
| New York Warehouse | 8722.8945 |

It's then just a case of aggregating over which ever columns you need.